# Show and hide grid view selected rows particular cell

Tags: asp.net, gridview, show-hide

Currently I'm working on one project.

There are total 5 columns in grid in which 2 are visible false.

```
name     email_id_X         email_id                 mobile_no_X   mobile_no   SELECT
-------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------
Mahesh  maXXXXXXahoo.co.in  maheshsbhoye@yahoo.co.in 98XXXXXX96    986769696   SELECT
Kiran   kiXXXXXX.in         kiran@yahoo.co.in        93XXXXXX333   9333333333  SELECT 
Kiran   kiXXXXXX.in         kiran@yahoo.co.in        93XXXXXX333   9333333333  SELECT 
Kiran   kiXXXXXX.in         kiran@yahoo.co.in        93XXXXXX333   9333333333  SELECT 
Amit    AmXXXXXXin          Amit@yahoo.co.in         93XXXXXX333   9333333333  SELECT
```

So please tell me how to hide the column email_id and mobile_no.
and when user click on select that time he can only see the selected rows email_id and mobile_no.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the RowCommand event. like..

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
        GridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        row.Cells[2].Visible = false;
        row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it will show entire columns. i don't want to show full columns i just want to show selected rows 2 and 4 column cell

Comment: if user select second row then kiXXXXXX.in  and 93XXXXXX333 hide and it will show kiran@yahoo.co.in and 9333333333. and entire data as it is in xxx format.

Answer (score 1):

First set `visible=false` for those two columns.
Then to get only the row u have selected, change the datasourceid and bind the data in the `gridview1_SelectedIndexchanged` event.

First the query for datasource it would be like `Select *  from table1`.
When you are binding for the second time, when you have clicked the select, then you're query should be like `Select * from table1 where emailid=xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

To hide certain columns you can have this in the code behind:

```
GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
GridView1.Columns[3].Visible = false;
```

This will hide the 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> columns of the `GridView`.

Comment: it will show entire columns. i don't want to show full columns i just want to show selected rows 2 and 4 column cell